# Erro de configuração da aplicação em Angular 2x

Tags: angular, angular-6

Eu fiz alguma ***** nos conselhos que o Visual Studio Code dá em algum arquivo de configuração e o que estava funcionando perfeitamente bem, agora ao rodar o `ng serve` dá o erro a seguir:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\common\http' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app'
ERROR in ./src/app/services/jogador.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\common\http' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\services'
ERROR in ./src/app/services/post.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\common\http' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\services'
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\core' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\core' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\core' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app'
ERROR in ./src/app/boostrap/cep/cep.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\core' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\boostrap\cep'
ERROR in ./src/app/bootstrap/alert/alert.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\core' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\bootstrap\alert'
ERROR in ./src/app/bootstrap/button/button.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\core' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\bootstrap\button'
ERROR in ./src/app/bootstrap/modal/modal.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\core' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\bootstrap\modal'
ERROR in ./src/app/jogador/jogador-form/jogador-form.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\core' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\jogador\jogador-form'
ERROR in ./src/app/login/login.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\core' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\login'
ERROR in ./src/app/post-list/post-list.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\core' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\post-list'
ERROR in ./src/app/post-save/post-save.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\core' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\post-save'
ERROR in ./src/app/services/local-storage.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\core' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\services'
ERROR in ./src/app/services/message.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\core' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\services'
ERROR in ./src/app/services/jogador.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\core' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\services'
ERROR in ./src/app/services/post.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\core' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\services'
ERROR in ./src/app/services/jwt-token.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\core' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\services'
ERROR in ./src/app/services/cep/cep.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\core' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\services\cep'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\forms' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\http' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app'
ERROR in ./src/app/login/login.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\http' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\login'
ERROR in ./src/app/services/cep/cep.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\http' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\services\cep'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\platform-browser' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app'
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\router' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app'
ERROR in ./src/app/jogador/jogador-form/jogador-form.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\router' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\jogador\jogador-form'
ERROR in ./src/app/login/login.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\router' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\login'
ERROR in ./src/app/post-save/post-save.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\@angular\router' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\post-save'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\ag-grid-angular' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app'
ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\ansi-html' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client'
ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\core-js\es7\reflect' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src'
ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\html-entities' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client'
ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\loglevel' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client'
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\ng2-file-upload' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app'
ERROR in ./src/app/login/login.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\rxjs' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\login'
ERROR in ./src/app/services/cep/cep.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\rxjs' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src\app\services\cep'
ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\sockjs-client\dist\sockjs' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client'
ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\strip-ansi' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client'
ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\url' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client'
ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\webpack\hot\emitter' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client'
ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\types\zone.js\dist\zone' in 'C:\mean\angular-crud-servicos\src'
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Já reinstalei com `npm install`mas tenho certeza que é em algum arquivo de configuração do ambiente. Alguém já passou por isso e como corrigiu?

Obrigado.

Segue meus arquivos de configuração:

tslint.json:

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "arrow-return-shorthand": true,
    "callable-types": true,
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [
      true,
      "check-space"
    ],
    "curly": true,
    "deprecation": {
      "severity": "warn"
    },
    "eofline": true,
    "forin": true,
    "import-blacklist": [
      true,
      "rxjs/Rx"
    ],
    "import-spacing": true,
    "indent": [
      true,
      "spaces"
    ],
    "interface-over-type-literal": true,
    "label-position": true,
    "max-line-length": [
      true,
      140
    ],
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      {
        "order": [
          "static-field",
          "instance-field",
          "static-method",
          "instance-method"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-bitwise": true,
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-construct": true,
    "no-debugger": true,
    "no-duplicate-super": true,
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-empty-interface": true,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-inferrable-types": [
      true,
      "ignore-params"
    ],
    "no-misused-new": true,
    "no-non-null-assertion": true,
    "no-redundant-jsdoc": true,
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-string-literal": false,
    "no-string-throw": true,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-unnecessary-initializer": true,
    "no-unused-expression": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "one-line": [
      true,
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-catch",
      "check-else",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],
    "prefer-const": true,
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single"
    ],
    "radix": true,
    "semicolon": [
      true,
      "always"
    ],
    "triple-equals": [
      true,
      "allow-null-check"
    ],
    "typedef-whitespace": [
      true,
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      }
    ],
    "unified-signatures": true,
    "variable-name": false,
    "whitespace": [
      true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ],
    "no-output-on-prefix": true,
    "use-input-property-decorator": true,
    "use-output-property-decorator": true,
    "use-host-property-decorator": true,
    "no-input-rename": true,
    "no-output-rename": true,
    "use-life-cycle-interface": true,
    "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
    "component-class-suffix": true,
    "directive-class-suffix": true
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": { "*": ["types/*"] },
    "paths": { "*": ["types/*"] },
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular-crud-servicos": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angular-crud-servicos",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-crud-servicos:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angular-crud-servicos:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-crud-servicos:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "angular-crud-servicos-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "angular-crud-servicos:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "angular-crud-servicos:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "angular-crud-servicos"
}
```

Se precisarem de outro arquivo de configuração me avisem. :/

Comment: Tenta rodar no diretório da sua aplicação: `npm install`

Comment: Tinha feito isso antes.

Comment: Resolvi. Não posso ficar procurando a ** que fiz, gerei novo projeto e copiei as pastas do projeto sem os arquivos de configuraçlão e funcionou. Agora... onde aceitei a sughestão do VSC que causou todo este erro, desconheço.

Comment: Ramos é por isso que é legal ter todo o versionamento do código, principalmente os arquivos de configuração. Assim você poderia saber exatamente o que causou isto.

Comment: Vou começar a fazer....